# Getting error when setting up payTM plugin in opencart v3.0.3.2

Tags: php, plugins, opencart, payment-gateway, paytm

I need help with the setting up payTM plugin in opencart v3.0.3.2, I'm getting following error when I click on extension setting:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in 
/home2/infipick/public_html/shop/system/library/paytm/PaytmConstants.php on line 14
```

I'm using php 7.3 on apache server which is hosted online and I used a theme called **nutripe** by thementic. I fllow all the needed step and getting following issue only on payment plugin.

Here are the files that I'm using of payTM plugin:

> **PaytmConstants.php**

```
    <?php

    class PaytmConstants{
        CONST TRANSACTION_URL_PRODUCTION            = "https://securegw.paytm.in/order/process";
        CONST TRANSACTION_STATUS_URL_PRODUCTION     = "https://securegw.paytm.in/order/status";

        CONST TRANSACTION_URL_STAGING               = "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/order/process";
        CONST TRANSACTION_STATUS_URL_STAGING        = "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/order/status";

        CONST SAVE_PAYTM_RESPONSE                   = true;
        CONST CHANNEL_ID                            = "WEB";
        CONST APPEND_TIMESTAMP                      = false;
        CONST ONLY_SUPPORTED_INR                    = true;
        CONST X_REQUEST_ID                          = "PLUGIN_OPENCART_" . VERSION;

        CONST MAX_RETRY_COUNT                       = 3;
        CONST CONNECT_TIMEOUT                       = 10;
        CONST TIMEOUT                               = 10;

        CONST LAST_UPDATED                          = "20200120";
        CONST PLUGIN_VERSION                        = "2.0";

        CONST CUSTOM_CALLBACK_URL                   = "";
    }

    ?>
```

> **PaytmHelper.php**

```
    <?php
    require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/paytm/PaytmConstants.php');

    class PaytmHelper{

        /**
        * include timestap with order id
        */
        public static function getPaytmOrderId($order_id){
            if($order_id && PaytmConstants::APPEND_TIMESTAMP){
                return $order_id . '_' . date("YmdHis");
            }else{
                return $order_id;
            }
        }
        /**
        * exclude timestap with order id
        */
        public static function getOrderId($order_id){       
            if(($pos = strrpos($order_id, '_')) !== false && PaytmConstants::APPEND_TIMESTAMP) {
                $order_id = substr($order_id, 0, $pos);
            }
            return $order_id;
        }

        /**
        * exclude timestap with order id
        */
        public static function getTransactionURL($isProduction = 0){        
            if($isProduction == 1){
                return PaytmConstants::TRANSACTION_URL_PRODUCTION;
            }else{
                return PaytmConstants::TRANSACTION_URL_STAGING;         
            }
        }
        /**
        * exclude timestap with order id
        */
        public static function getTransactionStatusURL($isProduction = 0){      
            if($isProduction == 1){
                return PaytmConstants::TRANSACTION_STATUS_URL_PRODUCTION;
            }else{
                return PaytmConstants::TRANSACTION_STATUS_URL_STAGING;          
            }
        }
        /**
        * check and test cURL is working or able to communicate properly with paytm
        */
        public static function validateCurl($transaction_status_url = ''){      
            if(!empty($transaction_status_url) && function_exists("curl_init")){
                $ch     = curl_init(trim($transaction_status_url));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
                $res    = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                return $res !== false;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static function getcURLversion(){        
            if(function_exists('curl_version')){
                $curl_version = curl_version();
                if(!empty($curl_version['version'])){
                    return $curl_version['version'];
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static function executecUrl($apiURL, $requestParamList) {
            $responseParamList = array();
            $JsonData = json_encode($requestParamList);
            $postData = 'JsonData='.urlencode($JsonData);
            $ch = curl_init($apiURL);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, PaytmConstants::CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, PaytmConstants::TIMEOUT);
            
            /*
            ** default value is 2 and we also want to use 2
            ** so no need to specify since older PHP version might not support 2 as valid value
            ** see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST.html
            */
            // curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

            // TLS 1.2 or above required
            // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json', 
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postData))
            );
            $jsonResponse = curl_exec($ch);   

            if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
                return json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }

    ?>
```

> **PaytmChecksum.php**
> <?php

```
    class PaytmChecksum{

        private static $iv = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";

        static public function encrypt($input, $key) {
            $key = html_entity_decode($key);

            if(function_exists('openssl_encrypt')){
                $data = openssl_encrypt ( $input , "AES-128-CBC" , $key, 0, self::$iv );
            } else {
                $size = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 'cbc');
                $input = self::pkcs5Pad($input, $size);
                $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', 'cbc', '');
                mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, self::$iv);
                $data = mcrypt_generic($td, $input);
                mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
                mcrypt_module_close($td);
                $data = base64_encode($data);
            }
            return $data;
        }

        static public function decrypt($encrypted, $key) {
            $key = html_entity_decode($key);
            
            if(function_exists('openssl_decrypt')){
                $data = openssl_decrypt ( $encrypted , "AES-128-CBC" , $key, 0, self::$iv );
            } else {
                $encrypted = base64_decode($encrypted);
                $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', 'cbc', '');
                mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, self::$iv);
                $data = mdecrypt_generic($td, $encrypted);
                mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
                mcrypt_module_close($td);
                $data = self::pkcs5Unpad($data);
                $data = rtrim($data);
            }
            return $data;
        }

        static public function generateSignature($params, $key) {
            if(!is_array($params) && !is_string($params)){
                throw new Exception("string or array expected, ".gettype($params)." given");            
            }
            if(is_array($params)){
                $params = self::getStringByParams($params);         
            }
            return self::generateSignatureByString($params, $key);
        }

        static public function verifySignature($params, $key, $checksum){
            if(!is_array($params) && !is_string($params)){
                throw new Exception("string or array expected, ".gettype($params)." given");
            }
            if(is_array($params)){
                $params = self::getStringByParams($params);
            }       
            return self::verifySignatureByString($params, $key, $checksum);
        }

        static private function generateSignatureByString($params, $key){
            $salt = self::generateRandomString(4);
            return self::calculateChecksum($params, $key, $salt);
        }

        static private function verifySignatureByString($params, $key, $checksum){
            $paytm_hash = self::decrypt($checksum, $key);
            $salt = substr($paytm_hash, -4);
            return $paytm_hash == self::calculateHash($params, $salt) ? true : false;
        }

        static private function generateRandomString($length) {
            $random = "";
            srand((double) microtime() * 1000000);

            $data = "9876543210ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$&_"; 

            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $random .= substr($data, (rand() % (strlen($data))), 1);
            }

            return $random;
        }

        static private function getStringByParams($params) {
            ksort($params);     
            $params = array_map(function ($value){
                return ($value == null) ? "" : $value;
            }, $params);
            return implode("|", $params);
        }

        static private function calculateHash($params, $salt){
            $finalString = $params . "|" . $salt;
            $hash = hash("sha256", $finalString);
            return $hash . $salt;
        }

        static private function calculateChecksum($params, $key, $salt){
            $hashString = self::calculateHash($params, $salt);
            return self::encrypt($hashString, $key);
        }

        static private function pkcs5Pad($text, $blocksize) {
            $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
            return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
        }

        static private function pkcs5Unpad($text) {
            $pad = ord($text{strlen($text) - 1});
            if ($pad > strlen($text))
                return false;
            return substr($text, 0, -1 * $pad);
        }
    }
```